# storing long strings (DNA sequence) in R

Tags: r, string

I have written a function that finds the indices of subsequences in a long DNA sequence. It works when my longer DNA sequence is < about 4000 characters. However, when I try to apply the same function to a much longer sequence, the console gives me a + instead of a >... which leads me to believe that it is the length of the string that is the problem.

for example: when the longer sequence is: "GATATATGCATATACTT", and the subsequence is: "ATAT", I get the indices "1, 3, 9" (0-based)

```
dnaMatch <- function(dna, sequence) {
  ret <- list()
  k <- str_length(sequence)
  c <- str_length(dna) - k 
  for(i in 1:(c+1)) {
    ret[i] = str_sub(dna, i, i+k-1)
  }
  ret <- unlist(ret)
  TFret <- lapply (ret, identical, sequence)
  TFret <- which(unlist(TFret), arr.ind = TRUE) -1
  print(TFret)
}
```

Basically, my question is... is there any way around the character-limitation in the string class?

Comment: "the console gives me a + instead of a >" - this is usually due to a missing `)`, `"`, `'`, or `}`. Did you double check your code for typos?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: the console gives me this when I try to set an arbitrary variable to a really long DNA sequence.

ie:
dna <- "ATAG - for 4000 characters - GTCA"

Comment: I see, I was able to replicate this issue by running `cat(paste0(rep("abcdef",1000),collapse=""))`, copying the output, and trying to assign this to an object `x <- "[paste copied text]"`. There is probably some kind of buffer limit.

Comment: i can replicate your example nrussell, but this assigns correctly `x<-paste0(rep("abcdef",1000),collapse="")`

Comment: she could also use regular expression matching efficiently in this case `?gregxpr` or `?regexpr` http://rfunction.com/archives/1719 http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

Comment: using `dnaMatch(x, 'ATATAT')` vs `gregexpr('ATATAT', x)` on a 100k length string was 49 seconds vs 0.003 seconds, resp. Sorry, didn't have the patience to run your loop for any longer

Comment: @bjoseph Right, but that isn't an option when the text to be assigned is not known *a priori*.  @Zoe someone may have a better solution, but I think you could either paste the text into a `.txt` file and read it in via `x <- readChars(<your_file.txt>, 10e6)`, or create the object in two or more parts with something like `x <- "[first segment]"; x <- paste0(x, "[second segment]",collapse="")`.

Answer (score 4):

I can replicate nrussell's example, but this assigns correctly `x<-paste0(rep("abcdef",1000),collapse="")`  -- a potential workaround is writing the character string to a `.txt` file and reading the `.txt` file into R directly:

test.txt is a 6,000 character long string.

```
`test<-read.table('test.txt',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
 length(class(test[1,1]))
[1] 1
class(test[1,1])
[1] "character"
 nchar(test[1,1])
[1] 6000`
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I eventually ended up doing!

Comment: cool! you should look into regular expression matching too. it can be a lifesaver in situations like these.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than write your own function, why not use the function words.pos in package seqinr. It seems to work even for strings up to a million base pairs.

For example,

```
library(seqinr)
data(ec999)
myseq <- paste(ec999[[1]], collapse="")
myseq <- paste(rep(myseq,100), collapse="")
words.pos("atat", myseq)
```

Comment: https://github.com/cran/seqinr/blob/master/R/words.pos.R That uses a `while` loop, grows objects, and `substr`.. probably not the fastest thing ever. And is just a wrapper for `regexpr` anyway

Comment: Not the fastest, but her example indicates she wants to find non-disjoint matches.

Comment: `Basically, my question is... is there any way around the character-limitation in the string class?` - I think her question is really about an issue with the R interpreter's buffer, i.e. it can only handle a limited amount of text being input to the console at once; not about the performance of her function.