# Way to increase string to support >4000 character limit?

Tags: r, memory

I have POST call that is sending data to an R script.  I need the script to support strings with >4000 characters.   Is there a way to increase memory limits on R to achieve this?

My question is related to [storing long strings (DNA sequence) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399710/storing-long-strings-dna-sequence-in-r).  However, I'm not able to manually load a .txt file since the R script is an API endpoint.

Is there a way with memory.limit() or some other means of increasing the upper bound on characters allowed in a string?

To recreate:

Run: `paste0(rep("abcdef",1000),collapse="")` and then copy/paste the resulting string to a new variable.

R doesn't close the end of the string.

Comment: What do you mean 4000 character limit? You can haver long strings in R...

Comment: "The number of bytes in a character string is limited to 2^31 - 1 ~ 2*10^9" I believe that is a hard limit. You'll need to split the string somehow.

Comment: `nchar(paste0(rep("abcdef",1000),collapse=""))` evaluates to 6000. Don't confuse the number of characters displayed in some consoles with the number of characters stored. Having said that, I don't even see any problem with displaying the full string, at least in RStudio.

Comment: There *does* seem to be a bug or limitation in the ability to use the clipboard (at least the Windows clipboard) when the clipboard contains large strings. That is a limitation on the ability of (some versions of?) R to interact with the clipboard and not the ability to store large strings.

Comment: R has a function `readClipboard()` which overcomes the clipboard limit. If you evaluate `nchar(paste0(rep("abcdef",1000),collapse=""))`, copy the resulting string (but *not* including the quote marks) then run `s <- readClipboard()`, you will get the string. (the clipboard contains a string of length 6002 if you include the quote marks).