# How to increase the maximum number of string in R?

Tags: r, string

I want to make an object including very long string.
But, when I tried to do that, I got an error:

```
Error: string containing Unicode escapes not in this locale
is too long (max 10000 chars)
```

I think the reason for the error is that the long string exceeds the capability of R. That is, the long string is too long to deal with.

I tried to divide the string into several objects, it works well.

But, I want to save the string only one object.

So, how can I increase the maximum number of string?

Comment: According to `help("Memory-limits")` there is a hard limit of 2^31-1 bytes. I would say you can't increase that. However, it seems likely that you don't need to. Storing such a large string in an R character vector doesn't seem sensible.

Comment: You mean you have a 10000+ 
character string constant  in your R script? Can't you just keep it in an external file so you could load it during runtime and  R parser would not have to deal with it?

Comment: Adding to comment of @margusl. You can also store your precreated objects using `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`

Comment: @Roland but isn't 2147483647 bytes >> 10000 characters desipte of encoding? It is ~210 KB / character

Comment: @asd-tm You are right. OP might actually hit a different limit. E.g., there should be a 2048 bytes limit from UCRT (which R uses on Windows).

Comment: @Roland There was an alike [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51671983/5043424) before without an upvoted/accepted answer

Comment: Thank you guys. Considering the suggestions, I found a solution. Thank you for your contributions.