# How to bypass RStudio console upper limit on character string length?

Tags: r, console, rstudio

I'm just starting to learn R, and I'm trying to write a function that translates an mRNA character string into a protein sequence. Hopefully someone with more experience can help me out pretty easily.

My function seems to work just fine on shorter strings, but when I try it on long RNA sequences, the console just prints a new line with `+` after the function call and nothing else. Nothing happens.

I found [this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872) which seems to say that there's a length limit of 4096 characters, but I can't find anything that indicates any way around this.

Is there a way to bypass this? 
Is there another environment I could try running my function in that will work with longer strings? 
I'd like to be able to pass strings of up to 10 000 characters as arguments to this function. Thanks in advance

Comment: A "+" in the console generally indicates that you forgot to close a pair of characters; _e.g._ parentheses in a function or quotes in a string.

Comment: Usually when the console prints a + and waits, it's because your code is incomplete

Comment: It prints a + and then waits. What would be an example of an incomplete code? I've checked my quotes and parentheses and they're both fine. It runs fine with short strings as arguments, just not a long string.

Comment: @Mach2 Can you test with a minimal reproducible example such as `s <- paste0(sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 10^5, replace = T), collapse = "")`. Just to clarify: There is no 4096 character limit in RStudio. So any issues you're experiencing must have another origin. Have you tried quitting RStudio and starting from a fresh session?

Comment: . Quit Session form the Session menu works.

Comment: Seems really is a duplicate of the cited question. There are workarounds in the answers;

Comment: @42- You're right...I didn't read the original cited question closely enough, and now I'm embarrassed. Thanks for the help! I'll try those workarounds tomorrow

Comment: There is another related question on SO: [R - Way to increase string to support >4000 character limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671983/r-way-to-increase-string-to-support-4000-character-limit); but again, there is no 4096 character "*upper limit on character string length*". What you're experiencing is a clipboard issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean or perhaps I misunderstood; there is definitely no 4096 character limit on `character` vectors in RStudio (or in R for that matter).

Here is a screenshot of a minimal reproducible example where I generate a string of length `10^5`

```
s <- paste0(sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 10^5, replace = T), collapse = "")
```

[image]

Comment: There is a limit on for console input lines.

Comment: @42- That's the issue I'm running into! Sorry, I worded my own problem wrong. Do you know how I would get around this limit so that I can pass a very long string of characters as an argument to my function?

Comment: @42- Hmm; I'm not sure what you mean. I take it you mean the *RStudio* console? There is definitely *no* upper limit on character string length in RStudio. This might be more related to a limit on the copy&paste buffer when *pasting* a long string into the console. But then I wonder why one would want to paste a long string into the RStudio console? Put it in a script, and there is no issue.

Comment: @42- PS. This seems to be a dupe of [R - Way to increase string to support >4000 character limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671983/r-way-to-increase-string-to-support-4000-character-limit).

Comment: Agreed. My dupe hammer is disabled because I already voted to close for another reason.

Comment: @42- And I can't close because the dupe target has no accepted/upvoted answer (only comments)...

Comment: It was teh Q linked in that other Q that was a good dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399710/storing-long-strings-dna-sequence-in-r

Comment: @42- I don't think that dupe post nails down on the actual issue (other than in one brief comment by nrussel). The issue here is not a string length limit in RStudio (or R) (ok, ignoring any hard OS or variable type-dependent limits); what OP describes only happens when you manually copy and insert a long string into the RStudio console. The answers to that post seem to miss that point and/or (deliberately or knowingly?) bypass the issue by reading long strings from file (avoiding the copy&paste step).

Comment: Reading from a file IS the "workaround" and the way to escape from the situation created by an over-aggressive pasting to the Rstudio console is to restart via the session menu and don't do it again. The Rstudio management knows about it and has chosen not to do anything because they think it is inherent in the R console interface.