# How to solve R not recognizing white-space after long line of code?

Tags: r, line-breaks

I am trying to add equations to my code which are quite long. When I do so, R does not quite grasp where the end of the equation is and when I go to the next line filled with whitespace, it puts the cursor to the middle of the line rather than the beginning, as usually.

[image]

When I run the code, it ignores the end of the long equation, as one can tell from the console output

```
+ # 3.b) Initialize ODEs
+ initialstate <- c( 
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"# 3.b) Initialize ODEs
initialstate"
```

-- so using + rather than > -- following this input:

```
C_PL_s_ss = (Rin_s*(CL_dis_s*T1*T2*V_IS + CL_dis_s*T1*T2*V_PE + CL_dis_s*T1*T2*V_PL + CL_dis_s*T1*T3_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*T1*T4_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*T2*T3_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*T2*T4_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*T2*T5_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*T2*T6_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*T1*T3_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*T1*T4_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*T2*T3_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*T2*T4_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*T2*T5_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*T2*T6_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*T1*T3_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*T1*T4_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*T2*T3_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*T2*T4_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*T2*T5_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*T2*T6_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*T1*T2*V_IS*delta_Rin_s_TI + CL_dis_s*T1*T3_s*V_IS*delta_Rin_s_TI + CL_dis_s*T1*T4_s*V_IS*delta_Rin_s_TI + CL_dis_s*T2*T3_s*V_IS*delta_Rin_s_TI + CL_dis_s*T2*T4_s*V_IS*delta_Rin_s_TI + CL_dis_s*T2*T5_s*V_IS*delta_Rin_s_TI + CL_dis_s*T2*T6_s*V_IS*delta_Rin_s_TI + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*V_IS*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*V_IS*V_PL*V_VC + CLup_s^2*T1*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T2*V_IS*V_PE*V_VC + CLup_s^2*T2*V_PE*V_PL*V_VC + CLup_s^2*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T5_s*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T6_s*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T3_s*V_PE*V_PL*V_VC + CLup_s^2*T4_s*V_PE*V_PL*V_VC + CLup_s^3*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T1*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T1*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*V_IS*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*V_PL*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T5_s*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T6_s*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T3_s*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T4_s*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T5_s*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T6_s*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T3_s*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T4_s*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T3_s*V_PL*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T4_s*V_PL*V_VC + CLup_s*T1*T2*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s*T1*T2*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s*T1*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s*T1*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s*T2*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s*T2*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s*T2*T5_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s*T2*T6_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s*T1*T3_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s*T1*T4_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s*T2*T3_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s*T2*T4_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s*T2*T5_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s*T2*T6_s*V_PE*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*V_IS*V_VC*delta_Rin_s_TI + CLup_s*T1*T2*V_IS*V_PE*delta_Rin_s_TI + CLup_s*T1*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE*delta_Rin_s_TI + CLup_s*T1*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE*delta_Rin_s_TI + CLup_s*T2*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE*delta_Rin_s_TI + CLup_s*T2*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE*delta_Rin_s_TI + CLup_s*T2*T5_s*V_IS*V_PE*delta_Rin_s_TI + CLup_s*T2*T6_s*V_IS*V_PE*delta_Rin_s_TI + CLup_s^2*T2*V_IS*V_PE*V_VC*delta_Rin_s_TI))/(CLR_s*CL_dis_s*T1*T2 + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*T1*T3_s + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*T1*T4_s + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*T2*T3_s + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*T2*T4_s + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*T2*T5_s + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*T2*T6_s + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*V_IS*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*Q*V_IS*V_VC + CLR_s*CLup_s^2*T1*V_IS*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s^2*T2*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T1*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T1*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T2*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T2*V_PL*V_VC + CLR_s*CLup_s^2*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s^2*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s^2*T5_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s^2*T6_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s^2*T3_s*V_PE*V_VC + CLR_s*CLup_s^2*T4_s*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T5_s*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T6_s*V_IS*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T3_s*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T4_s*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T5_s*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T6_s*V_IS*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T3_s*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T4_s*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T3_s*V_PL*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^2*T4_s*V_PL*V_VC + CLR_s*CLup_s^3*V_IS*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^3*V_IS*V_PE*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s^3*V_IS*V_PL*V_VC + CLup_s^2*Q*T2*V_PE*V_VC + CLup_s^2*Q*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s^2*Q*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s^2*Q*T5_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s^2*Q*T6_s*V_IS*V_PE + CLup_s^2*Q*T3_s*V_PE*V_VC + CLup_s^2*Q*T4_s*V_PE*V_VC + CLup_s^3*Q*V_IS*V_PE*V_VC + CLup_s^2*T1*T2*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T1*T3_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T1*T4_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T2*T3_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T2*T4_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T2*T5_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^2*T2*T6_s*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^3*T1*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^3*T2*V_PE*V_PL*V_VC + CLup_s^3*T3_s*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^3*T4_s*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^3*T5_s*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^3*T6_s*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL + CLup_s^3*T3_s*V_PE*V_PL*V_VC + CLup_s^3*T4_s*V_PE*V_PL*V_VC + CLup_s^4*V_IS*V_PE*V_PL*V_VC + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T1*V_IS + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*V_VC + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T3_s*V_IS + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T4_s*V_IS + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T5_s*V_IS + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T6_s*V_IS + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T3_s*V_VC + CLR_s*CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T4_s*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*Q*T2*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*Q*T3_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*Q*T4_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*Q*T5_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*Q*T6_s*V_IS + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*Q*T3_s*V_VC + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*Q*T4_s*V_VC + CLR_s*CLup_s*T1*T2*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T1*T2*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T1*T2*V_PL + CLR_s*CLup_s*T1*T3_s*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s*T1*T4_s*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s*T2*T3_s*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s*T2*T4_s*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s*T2*T5_s*V_PE + CLR_s*CLup_s*T2*T6_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T1*T3_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T1*T4_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*T3_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*T4_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*T5_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*T6_s*V_PE + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T1*T3_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T1*T4_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*T3_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*T4_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*T5_s*V_PL + CL_dis_s*CLup_s*T2*T6_s*V_PL)


# 3.b) Initialize ODEs
initialstate <- c(*[...some other cade that work unless you add the long equation above...])*
```

Bizarrely, if I write more than one of these longer equations, it recognises the end of exactly every second one, i.e. it pairs two, which leads to the issue. For the ones that it does not pair, it also has the > rather than + in the respective place in the console. I could get it to work fine for 5 short equations.

As I am exporting the equations from Matlab (as I need to use the symbolics toolbox to find the solution), I checked whether any of

- cutting whitespaces out online, incl. equation by equation, so line by line
- pasting the many equations into Word to see whether there is a difference in the tabs/new lines etc. between the equations for which the pasting interrupts between equations appropriately versus not (no both are the same)
- past into text editor before moving to R, incl. equation by equation, so line by line
- using my local version of R studio rather than the R studio workbench I was using previously

would help but they did not.

I have tried for a long time now and would be super grateful for any insight!

Comment: Your code that you posted ends in `initialstate <- c(`. Is that not where your error comes from? Is there any reason why you can't put your code across multiple lines? It will be much easier to read

Comment: If tha'ts not the case, you've probably run into a limit of how many bytes can be on the console at once by default https://stackoverflow.com/q/54974996/5325862

Comment: @camille, thank you very much for sharing your thoughts. The `initialstate <- c(` bit continues with some code that runs unless you add the longer lines of code and a closing bracket. I have now made that obvious - apologies for not doing so earlier.  I will try breaking it up over multiple lines. I just did not see the point as it is not a part to ever be edited and it complicates the transfer of the output from MATLAB. There will be a larger number of long equations and it would be nice to automate the transfer but I can work on shaping the MATLAB output in case this solves it. Thanks!

Comment: This is just a typeo somewhere in your code. If you highlight your equation and hit ctrl+shift+A it will reformat it more appropriately so you can inspect.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @jpsmith! Following the advice that line breaks may help and the equation may be too long, I split the top of the fraction (numerator) and bottom (denominator) and calculated each separately. I then set `C_PL_s_ss = numerator/denominator ` and everything works fine. This is lots of manual input, which I wanted to avoid but shows that there should not be a typo. It's interesting that when I do your shortcut, the numerator is sorted and the denominator one long line/not changed (feel free to try). R does not have a problem with shorter fractions like `y=(x+(w*m+a*n))/(b+c)`

Comment: [This thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872/4) suggests that there is a maximum line length of 4096 characters. Your line has about 5400 characters.

Comment: Thank you, @Gregor Thomas! I guess that is the solution to it all then :) Thanks for getting me on the right path so quickly, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is built with a maximum line length of 4096 characters [as shown in this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872/4). Lines that are longer than that will need to be broken.